# Efficient Taylor-like series for the inverse of a sum of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, power-series

everyone!

Here is an interesting question.

Imagine that you want to compute the following: $\left( \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \right)^{-1}$, but you do not want to find it explicitly as the overall size of $\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B}$ is way too big to do that. And even if you have enough RAM, it is just time-consuming.

Basically, I know that there is a simplification of a Woodbury's formula, which gives the following:
\begin{gather}
\left( \mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} \right)^{-1} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( - \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{B}  \right)^k \mathbf{A}^{-1}, \quad (1)
\end{gather}

It is known that this expansion above can be useful if $\mathbf{B}$ is a perturbation of $\mathbf{A}$.
However, I have the following question: what if I have some additional information on $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$?

For instance, imagine, that $\mathbf{B}$ is indeed a small perturbation, so that $||\mathbf{B}|| < (\text{or even } \ll) \: \: ||\mathbf{A}||$.

Also consider that the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is block-diagonal, so that each block is reasonably small, and can be diagonalized easily. Does the information about the spectrum of $\mathbf{A}$ allow me to write something similar to the Woodbury formula above in a Taylor-like fashion that will allow for a series that converges faster than Eq. (1)?

I understand that the knowledge on $\mathbf{A}$'s spectrum allows to efficiently compute $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, but what about the overall convergence of the series? Can it be improved with this knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

The series converges if $\|A^{-1} B\| < 1$.  It suffices to have $\|B\| < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$, as $\|A^{-1} B\| \le \|A^{-1}\| \|B\|$.  But no condition on $\|A\|$ and $\|B\|$ will be enough: e.g. consider $$A = \pmatrix{M & 0\cr 0 & 1/M}, B = \pmatrix{1/M & 0\cr 0 & -1/M}$$ for $M > 1$, where $\|B\| = 1/M$, $\|A\| = M$, but the series diverges and $(A+B)^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your response! You comment, indeed, makes sense, but it only touches the overall converges of the series (whether it converges or not at all).

My question is more on the following: considering that the operators are so "good" that everything converges. The question is: how I can manipulate the splitting of the overall operator into $\mathbf{A}$, and $\mathbf{B}$ (or any other trick!) that will help to build a series that converges faster than a commonly used and presented above!